# Owl Carousel and shopify

Tags: shopify, owl-carousel

I am creating a webpage powered by shopify and it gives me the option to customize the page. I am trying to put in an owl carousel and in one of the themes it works perfectly (pop theme), but when placed in another theme (debut theme), it does not work. It shows the images the stylesheets and scripts do not seem to be reading.

```js
  <script src="{{ 'jquery-3.1.1.min.js' | asset_url }}"></script>  
  <script src="{{ 'owl.carousel.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
    <script src=" {{ 'owl.carousel.min.js' | asset_url }}"></script>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
              owl.owlCarousel({
                margin: 10,
                nav: true,
                loop: true,
                autoplay:true,
                autoplayTimeout:2000,
                autoplayHoverPause:true,
              
                responsive: {
                  0: {
                    items: 1
                  },
                  600: {
                    items: 3
                  },
                  1000: {
                    items: 5
                  }
                }
              })
            })
          </script>
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'owl.carousel.css' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'owl.theme.default.css' | asset_url }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'owl.carousel.min.css' | asset_url}}">
  

        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1777/9785/files/c_a_3.jpg?16781934716315122188"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

These were the codes i used, i don't know whats preventing it from reading the codes in the debut theme, but it either shows no images at all, or shows the images in a straight vertical line. I've been struggling with it for 2 days, if someone had an answer i'd be very grateful.

Comment: Why are you adding `owl.carousel.js` twice? Correct this and your problem should solve itself. Also the scripts should be above the HTML content.

Comment: Have you verified all the scripts and css files are loading, and you've added them to your asset folder with the exact same name as you listed in script src? (view source to see if they load)